# Constant location requests from Facebook - how to turn off?

Tags: applications, facebook, geolocation, facebook-messenger

My location request icon is constantly on. When I hit the location request notification, it tells me that Facebook and Google Play Services are high battery usage. When I force stop Facebook, the location request icon immediately disappears.

How can I stop Facebook from constantly requesting my location? It's killing my battery. I'm not rooted.

Comment: Is this for the Facebook app or the Facebook Messenger app?

Comment: Facebook app only. I have messenger installed too though, but the location requests stopped only when I uninstalled the FB app. Seems like uninstalling/reinstalling it might have helped a bit?

Comment: I've done some testing on this using my phone (I'm rooted on CM11s) and I have the benefit of privacy guard.

What I've noticed is that the Facebook app tends to ask for your location a LOT. Always when you open the app, but even sometimes when I haven't used the app for days...

It's not really an answer, but worth noting.